# angular-material-extensions/select-country - Cannot get the resource

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to use the extension, **angular-material-extensions/select-country**. The installation instruction comes from here, https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/select-country.

I did follow the instruction: **installing via npm**, and the result looks like this

[image]

as you can see, it cannot show the corresponding country flag. I got the error

> ERROR Error: Error retrieving icon :zm! Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/assets/svg-country-flags/svg/zm.svg: 404 Not Found

I guess the problem that the app cannot find out where the images are located. But I do not really know how to fix this.

Comment: This usually happens when the  returns some HTML when it can't find something, instead of a 404 error code. It means that the server failed the request for some reason.  . Usually you can debug it by looking at the Network tab in the dev tools and checking what the response looks like. Add more code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there is an error in library documentation with path.
Angular 12.

In angular.json I fixed path and flags started to show correctly:

```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "./node_modules/svg-country-flags/svg",
        "output": "/assets/svg-country-flags/svg"
      }
    ],
```